# Two computers to one new one using time machine

Tags: time-machine, imac

I want to transfer both my computers info to the new one.  I did it, but it came out in two different places.  Can I merger the two?

Answer (score 1):

**(It probably goes without saying, but I haven't actually tried this myself. YMMV. Make backups before you start this. Use at your own risk, etc.)**

You probably can, but if there are conflicts between them, one of them will have to be the designated 'winner'.

The easiest way to do this is probably to run `/Applications/Utilities/Migration Assistant.app` twice. Whichever one you run last will overwrite any of the existing settings from the other one.

A more complicated way to do this would be to use `rsync` to move the files to the same destination, however it should be noted that `rsync` is one of the Un*x tools which is hugely powerful *and* very easy to misuse to disastrous effect. Be sure that you have a separate backup of these files before you try to use `rsync` on them.

A third option would be to use [Transmit](http://panic.com/transmit/) which has the ability to move folders and merge them. You'll have to decide which one 'wins' but it’s probably a more granular approach than Migration Assistant without getting into the complexity of `rsync`.